# Make 2 JButtons Equal in size

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have two `JButton`s with texts "Ok" and "Cancel". I am using `GridBagLayout` to align them in a `JDialog`. I have set the anchor to `GridBagConstraints.CENTER`. Due to the difference in the number of characters in the texts "Ok" and "Cancel", the buttons are of different sizes. How do I align them correctly so that each of them have the same size. I tried the following but no avail.

```
okayButton.setSize(cancelButton.getSize());
```

Comment: just for emphasis: sizing/positioning the components is the job of the LayoutManager (which you already use, good!) - setSize in application code has (and is expected to and must have :-) _no_ effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the fill to `GridBagConstraints.BOTH` and give both buttons equal weight.

Answer (score 1):

[GridBaglayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) have got [GridBagConstraints](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html#gridbagConstraints) and in all cases accepts `PreferredSize`

examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1460__GridBagLayout.htm) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1480__GridBagConstraints.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `okayButton.setSize(cancelButton.getSize());`
use `okayButton.setPreferredSize(cancelButton.getPreferredSize());`

Comment: -1 no ... never-ever use setXXSize in application code (for some reasons, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swing) instead use a decent LayoutManager

Comment: By the way, should I remove answers those may mislead people?